# Proof of a certain inequality in two-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, fractional-calculus

Please think it easy because it is not an assignment.

I'm trying to show the following problem.

> Show that the inequality
>   $$
> 12(x^{5/2}+y^{5/2})+15(\sqrt{x}y^{2}+x^{2}\sqrt{y})>25(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})xy+18(x-y)^{5/2}
> $$
>   holds on $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^{2}\mid\frac{2}{3}x<y\le x\}$.

For the function
$$
f(x,y)=12(x^{5/2}+y^{5/2})+15(\sqrt{x}y^{2}+x^{2}\sqrt{y})-25(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})xy-18(x-y)^{5/2},
$$
I could prove that it is positive on $y=x$ and $y=\frac{2}{3}x$, and also know **numerically** that this function is positive on the above set.
I however can not give a rigorous proof.
It seems to be no use only by evaluating it below simply.

I'm glad if you give me a hint or solution.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Progress** :

By setting $z=\frac{y}{x}$, I know that the above inequality is reduced to 
$$
12(z^{5/2}+1)+15(z^{2}+\sqrt{z})>25(\sqrt{z}+1)z+18(1-z)^{5/2}
$$
on $\{z\in(0,1]\mid\frac{2}{3}<z\le 1\}$.

Comment: You can replace $18(1-z)^\frac{5}{2}$ with it maximum $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Replace $\sqrt{z}$ by $x$. Then you obtain a polynomial of degree $5$. Its derivative is of order $4$, if you can solve that, you are done. Otherwise, I cannot think of a different way.